# Como imprimir un diccionario especifico dentro de un archivo txt?

Tags: python, archivo, diccionarios

Tengo varios diccionarios dentro de un archivo .txt escritos de esta forma

```
{identidad1:{a:b, c:d, e:f}
{identidad2:{g:h, i:j, k:l}
{identidad3:{m:n, o:p, q:r}
```

Ahora necesito imprimir solamente un diccionario, basándose en el termino "identidadX" que se recibe mediante un `input`, como puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Ya probaste escribir directo con un for??

Comment: @AlfaRojo Como?

Comment: para python cada una de esas claves es una variable, por lo que sería muy trabajoso obtenerlo así sin más para eso deberíamos de "pre-procesarlo" para convertir cada clave y valor en un string

Comment: Como llegas a tener el archivo de diccionarios? Los creas con otro programa?

Comment: @DanteS. Si, le hago varias preguntas al usuario y poco a poco se van a agregando los valores, las keys las genero yo con el nombre que va asociado a estos en los respectivos diccionarios y luego las añado al archivo txt.

Comment: Sabes como escribir en el archivo?? Conoces los ciclos for de python?? Combinando ambos, me suena a que funcionaría. Por cada elemento en el diccionario, escribes la clave, seguida del valor... Y así

Comment: @AlfaRojo Sí, esos diccionarios están dentro del archivo, lo que necesito es traer uno de esos diccionario a la consola.

Comment: Aaaa yo pensaba que te referias de una entrada de consola, exportarlo a un archivo... Entonces sii ya lees el archivo, en la variable que tenes almacenada la información, la lectura, allí realizá el mismo bucle que te dije, e ir imprimiendo cada parte

Comment: Que tal si cuando creas y cargas el contenido del archivo usas el modulo [json](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/json.html)? El modulo json convierte un diccionario en un object y las cadenas en, bueno, cadenas xD (ver [tabla de conversion](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table))